# Two different create.js.erb files for two different pages (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my application i have comments which are creating without reloading.

**comments_controller**

```
  def create
    ...
    @comment.save 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @comments)) %>");
```

Comments can be posted on two pages, both of these two pages use create.js.erb.
I want **only** first page use *create,js,erb*, and another page use *anothercreate.js.erb*
How can i do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `render` to specify which view you want rendered

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.js {render "anothercreate.js.erb" }
end
```

This link has more info on rendering, and all the different ways you can write the call to `render` to get it to use the correct view: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Thanks for answer! But format.js {render "anothercreate.js.erb" } will render anothercreate.js.erb on all pages where comments can be created, right? How can i render anothercreate.js.erb on specific page?